# Proving that set is (or is not) a field

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Let $P = \{a + b\sqrt[3]3 + c\sqrt[3]9, a, b, c \in \Bbb Z \}$

It is easy to prove that $(P, +, \cdot)$ is a ring considering ordinary addition and multiplication. How to prove that this set is or is not a field? I am stuck. I think that showing that there is an inverse element (or there is not) for all elements is the key, but I don't know how to do it. I tried "rationalizing" 
$\frac{1}{a + b\sqrt[3]3 + c\sqrt[3]9}$ but got stuck. Not really good with this stuff. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P = \mathbb Z[\alpha]$, where $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{3}$. Since $P$ is the image of $\mathbb Z[X]$ under $X\mapsto \alpha$, it is clear that $P$ is a ring. Now, $2\in P$ but $1/2 \not\in P$ because $1,\alpha,\alpha^2$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$. So, $P$ is not a field.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't remember to try for a particular element.

Comment: @darxsys Don't overlook that you must *prove* that $\,1/2 \not\in P.\,$ Do you see how to do that?

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks for that, but isn't that already proved by lhf's explanation? I am a bit confused.

Comment: @darxsys Yes, I just wanted to emphasize that it needed proof, and be sure that you saw how to do so, since this is a place where many students make errors.

Comment: @BillDubuque how would you prove it?